# How to implement CompletableFuture with a priority execution?

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, completable-future

I have an issue where I am not sure if the completable future api is able to solve my problem, but would like to open it to the stack overflow community.

I have a case, where I want to call 2 methods. One of these methods (method A) will return some data from DynamoDB. Another method (method B) will return some data from a SQL database. I would like to do these methods in parallel. However, the twist is the customer can ask for data in a certain priority.

For example, a user could pass in `["A" , "B"]. In this case, I would like both tasks to start being done in parallel, but if A finishes and returns useful data to stop execution on task B. If A returns null/not found, then return the result of B.

When reading about completable future's I have not found any methods that seem to be able to do this. The methods  `anyOf(CompletableFuture<?>... cfs)` or     `allOf(CompletableFuture<?>... cfs)` seem to apply to these situations. It seems like there is no way to give a preference to a specific CompletableFuture.

I would love to know how to solve this problem in Java!

Comment: `CompletableFuture` does not support stopping a task. Using an `ExecutorService` directly, you can cancel a `Future` with interruption, but this still requires the actual operation to support interruption. If the SQL database resp. its driver does not support interrupting an operation, you can save your time by not trying to implement stopping the task.

Comment: Hello there Holger, thank you for your comment. Since I'm using quarkus, the reactive framework I am looking into is Mutiny , Vert.x. Do you know if its possible to create the above experience with that library? I feel like I only see `join`. and `all()` and `first`. It seems like there is no other way to give a particular async request priority other than waiting for both to end or for any of them to return a result.

Comment: Doc links : https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides/joining-unis , https://javadoc.io/static/io.smallrye.reactive/mutiny/1.1.1/io/smallrye/mutiny/groups/UniJoin.html , https://javadoc.io/static/io.smallrye.reactive/mutiny/1.1.1/io/smallrye/mutiny/Uni.html